# Use rollsum and combine two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have two data sets, purchases and contacts. They only share id of the user and week number.

The contacts table has the week number when a contact was made with the user. This value is either 1 (contact) or 0 (no contact).

The purchases table has the week number when a purchase was made by the user.

I want to calculate, given the purchases week number, if there was a contact made in the previous n weeks (can be 4, 8 or 12), starting from the current week (i.e., 4 previous weeks means current week + 3 past weeks). The week number is fixed, from 1 to 147.

How do I do this?

The data looks like this:

```
purchase = data.frame(user_id = c(156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086), week_number =  c(1, 5, 9, 13, 16, 21, 30, 38, 42, 46, 50, 53, 72, 76, 83, 93, 98, 103, 110, 120, 124, 128, 133, 137, 141))

contact = data.frame(user_id = c(156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086, 156086), week_number = c(99, 120, 101, 105, 119, 117, 118, 119, 117, 118, 119, 116, 115, 118, 119, 116, 118), contacted = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I just put one user, but there are ~40k users. The expected result for this user would be (I omitted user_id as it is the same as before):

```
output = data.frame(week_number =  c(1, 5, 9, 13, 16, 21, 30, 38, 42, 46, 50, 53, 72, 76, 83, 93, 98, 103, 110, 120, 124, 128, 133, 137, 141), contacted = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0))
```

The fist thought I had was to do a for loop over the users, and for each user create an array from 1 to 147 (week number), insert when a contact was made given the week number, apply rollsum with lag; then, using the week number from the purchases, see if there was a contact given the weeks in the purchase table. But this takes a while.

Is there a way to calculate this in one line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve with a rolling join of the *data.table*-package. With:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(purchase)
setDT(contact)
out <- contact[purchase, .(user_id = i.user_id, week_number, contacted),
               on = "week_number", roll = 4, nomatch = NA
               ][is.na(contacted), contacted := 0]
```

you get:

```
> out
    user_id week_number contacted
 1:  156086           1         0
 2:  156086           5         0
 3:  156086           9         0
 4:  156086          13         0
 5:  156086          16         0
 6:  156086          21         0
 7:  156086          30         0
 8:  156086          38         0
 9:  156086          42         0
10:  156086          46         0
11:  156086          50         0
12:  156086          53         0
13:  156086          72         0
14:  156086          76         0
15:  156086          83         0
16:  156086          93         0
17:  156086          98         0
18:  156086         103         1
19:  156086         110         0
20:  156086         120         1
21:  156086         124         1
22:  156086         128         0
23:  156086         133         0
24:  156086         137         0
25:  156086         141         0
```

---

*Explanation*:

With `setDT` you convert the dataframes to datatbales (which are an enhanced form of dataframe). Using the `purchase` dataframe/datatable as a reference for the `contact` dataframe/datatable in combination with `nomatch = NA`, `.(user_id=i.user_id, week_number, contacted)` and `roll = 4` returns a datatable with matches when in the previous 4 weeks the customer has been contacted.

Comment: I get an error: "unused argument (on = "week_number")". Haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: @Andres did you convert the dataframes to datatables with the `setDT` arguments?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code you wrote to run the example I posted. I am seeing if it is a version issue of data.table package.

Comment: @Andres Do you have the latest CRAN version of data.table (v1.9.6)? You need that (or the development version 1.9.7) to use the `on` argument.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue, upgrading now. Thanks Jaap!